# Image is not uploading in localhost

Tags: image, http, upload, localhost

I am uploading two image in my project. In online images are uploading there is no problem. But when i am trying in localhost it showing "This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500". What could be solution please help me guys thanks in advance. Here's my code below..

```
       if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/customer';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['file_name']     = time() . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

        //Load upload library and initialize configuration
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $uploadData        = $this->upload->data();
            $data['CustPhoto'] = $uploadData['file_name'];
        } else {
            echo "filenot upload";
        }
    } else {
        $data['message'] = "Please select Your Photo ";
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('Sr_user/customer_manage');
    }

    if (!empty($_FILES['userfile1']['name'])) {
        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/customer';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['file_name']     = time() . $_FILES['userfile1']['name'];

        //Load upload library and initialize configuration
        //$this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile1')) {
            $uploadData              = $this->upload->data();
            $data['NationalIdPhoto'] = $uploadData['file_name'];

        } else {
            echo "filenot upload";
        }
    } else {
        $data['message'] = "Please select Your National Id Image ";
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

       redirect('Sr_user/customer_manage');
    }

    $this->Super_admin_model->add_action($data, 'member_manage');
```

Comment: have you tried altering the upload path to reflect the new location as it appears that you are still using the online variation.

Comment: what should i do now?